# How to distinguish between pointers to overloaded functions?

Tags: c, class, function-pointers

I have a `class`

```
struct MyClass
{
    ...
    bool (* IsValid)(MyClass * self, int type);
    bool (* IsValid)(MyClass * self, char * str);
};
```

relevant functions

```
bool IsValidMyClass(BitMask * self, int mask)
{
    ...
}
bool IsValidMyClass(BitMask * self, char * str)
{
    ...
}
```

and a `CTOR`-like function

```
MyClass BuildMyClass()
{
    res.IsValid = IsValidMyClass; //(MyClass * self, int type);
    res.IsValid = IsValidMyClass; //(MyClass * self, char * str);
    return res;
}
```

And here I got in confuse - how to say to compiler to do a correct assignment?

Comment: That won't compile as you can't have two members of a struct with the same name in C

Comment: There are no overloaded functions in C. `BitMask & self` is not a valid C declaration. Perhaps you are studying the wrong language.

Comment: This is obviously C++. You need to change the tag.

Comment: My mistake in code sample. Replacing `&` to `*` - in this context it doesn't matter

Comment: In C++, you probably would declare methods instead of function pointers. It's kind of a phantasy language, trying to *do C++ in C*. But C doesn't know *references*, to start with.

Comment: @Jury Did you want to compile this code with a C compiler _or_ is it C-like code to be complied with a C++ compiler?

Comment: There is still no function overloading in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overloaded functions are not allowed in C.  You also can't have two members of a `struct` with the same name.

You need to give them each distinct names.  Also, there is no reference operator `&` in C.  You probably want to pass a pointer.

```
struct MyClass
{
    ...
    bool (* IsValidByType)(MyClass *self, int type);
    bool (* IsValidByStr)(MyClass *self, char * str);
};

bool IsValidMyClassByType(BitMask *self, int mask)
{
    ...
}
bool IsValidMyClassByStr(BitMask *self, char * str)
{
    ...
}

MyClass BuildMyClass()
{
    res.IsValidByType = IsValidMyClassByType;
    res.IsValidByStr = IsValidMyClassByStr;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ took over C's function pointer syntax. However with virtual members of classes doing essentially the same thing as a function pointer, you seldom need C style function pointers in C++.

If you have an overloaded function, C++ will resolve by matching the types in the function pointer's argument list.